# Inserting Items and SubItems to a Order

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, model

I need to be able to add subItems to my orders system.

I have this structure:

[image]

The subitem is like an additional model for a dish.

As for example in a burger, in case the client wants to add a lettuce, tomato or onion. It also needs the item_id to identify which item of that order the subitem belongs to.

Then I end up with this model:

[Fixed Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ6Et.png)

- Is this the best way to doing this ?
- Am I going to have performance problems when querying ?

EDITS:

1. The reason of the item_id in Order_SubItems is to reference the Item_id that the subitem belong.
2. Them same order can have multiple Items of the same ID. But they can only have one type of each SubItem.
3. Maybe I will need an item_pos column to know what item the subitem belongs in case to have 2 items with the same id.

Comment: What is items_id?

Comment: In the food example, could an order have two burgers, or would those be separate orders?

Comment: The number of Items and SubItems are infinite.

Comment: Related link at dba stackexchange. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132970/database-design-for-ordering-complex-products

Comment: @Drealler it doesn't matter how many items/subitems there are, I am asking if a single order can have the same item twice. What I was getting at is that two burgers(same item) could be ordered, each with different toppings(sub-items). This implies "Orders_SubItems" should be "Order_Items_SubItems" and that "Order_Items" should have a row id for it to reference.

Comment: @Uueerdo Now I understant and YES the same order can have 2 or more items of same ID but they can only have 1 type of each topping

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicate?

order and order_items are exactly what you need. Add a is_incredient (TINYINT) or is_extra (TINYINT) column to the order_items and that was it.

It's not necessary to split up the price, name and quantity.

Comment: Because a Item can have infinite SubItems and they can change the Items price.

Answer (score 0):

**Performance Problem (depends on how you fetch - eager/lazy loading)**

Database design has less importance in performance on Laravel rather the implementation of your design on Laravel (how you gonna implement your design) is important. If you implement any complex model in Laravel correctly by utilizing all the performance measures then of-course its does not matter how complex or how many relation you introduce in your Database side.

I would like to recommend you to install [laravel debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) and compare your number of queries and performance based on different design. When you get enough idea on Laravel debug bar then implement caching, indexing techniques of laravel. There is whole new world of Laravel performance tuning.

**NOTE:** The design and complexity of the database determines the performance somehow but the actual performance is how you are going to implement that in Laravel.

Please look at:

- Laravel Debug Bar
- Eager loading vs Lazy loading (Eloquent)
- Object Caching, Config Caching
- MySQL Indexing
- Optimize Command (Artisan Ccommands)
- Route Cache
- Database Chunking

You can find lots of tutorials on above topics just you need to search for the performance of the Laravel. Do not be afraid to introduce any complex model (Database Design) with Laravel. That's how you are going to learn "how to optimize" or "do you really need to cut off any models". No one can suggest you the best database design unless and until get full requirement specification document (App Detail). Its better if you design your app based on different performance measures available in laravel.

I am posting this in the response of your performance query and performance tuning.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial structure looks really good -- Id just recommend a few simple modifications.

To solve the sub-items, I'd suggest using a single model for all items on the order by simply adding a parent_id and then referencing that on the sub-items.

For example, lets add a burger with items_id 1 and a null parent_id.  Then if we want to add some delicious bacon, it becomes items_id 2 with parent_id 1. Extra patty, same idea ... that becomes items_id 3 with parent_id 1.  The nice thing about this structure, is you can have essentially infinite sub-items ... and as many levels deep as you need.

I might also suggest adding the price to the order_items models as well, to capture the the point of sale price.  This way if the item price changes (Or you have a sale, coupon, discount, etc.) your historical numbers are retained.

You may also want to convert all currency fields (price, total, etc.) to cents and store them in the database as integers.  That will generally give you better performance (over varchar), works well all major currencies and avoids some of the rounding issues that can occur with decimal data types.